# Change DIV based on clicked TAB

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a leaderboard for a website we are working on.

Essentially, we have a div with this months winner for location A

Below we have ajax tabs, where user can click tabs which relate to locations, like :

Location A
Location B
etc etc

So by default, when page loads, tab A is open. And the div above we need to give a matching ID, because...

I want as the user clicks tab B for the div above to change, with different DIV ID. So basically we can change content in the div based on the  tab the user clicks.

So the content div is like:

```
<div id="???"> content goes here </div>
```

The tabs are like:

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
                    <li><a href="#tab1"><span class="stateTab">NSW</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#tab2"><span class="stateTab">QLD</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#tab3"><span class="stateTab">VIC</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#tab4"><span class="stateTab">SA</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#tab5"><span class="stateTab">WA</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#tab6"><span class="stateTab">ACT</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#tab7"><span class="stateTab">NT</span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#tab8"><span class="stateTab">TAS</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/leaderboard/australia/"><span class="stateTab">AUSTRALIA</span></a></li>
                </ul>
```

So if user clicks #tab2 then a different DIV loads into the div id="???" .

I think its fairly simple, just cannot figure it out. I realise I possibly have to set all the divs up, like so:

```
<div id="tab1"> content goes here </div>
<div id="tab2"> content goes here </div>
<div id="tab2"> content goes here </div>
```

And set visibility hidden to the divs.. any help appreciated.

*** *ADDED INFO* *********

The tabs, onclick ( presently ) display content from dataTables.
So obviously when we click on tab1, the content below the tabs , shows the content fetched from our dataTables, in a div with id1

The issue now is, with wanting to change the content ABOVE the tabs aswell as the content BELOW the tabs... the 2 id's are conflicting, and one shows and one hides...

The TABS also change content below them, presumably we need to chain the id actions somehow, to get two sets of content to change in harmony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it up the way you planned in HTML adding style="display: none" to each div except the one you want to show by default. Then add to you javascript (at the bottom, or in `$(function(){ //Document ready });`

```
$('.tabs a').click(function(){
        $('div[id^=tab]').hide();
        $(this.href).show();
        return false;
    }
);
```

As for your Update, you can change your divs to have a class instead of an id. Like 
     Content Above 1
     Content Above 2

Tabs

```
 <div class="tab1 tabContent">Content Below 1</div>
 <div class="tab2 tabContent">Content Below 2</div>
```

Then you can change the javascript:

```
$('.tabs a').click(function(){
        $('div.tabContent').hide();
        $('div.'+this.href).show();
        return false;
    }
);
```

You'll also need to remove the hashes from your anchors, so the href becomes "tab1" instead of "#tab1"

Comment: Right, didn't notice the hash already in the href. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: @PaulPRO , ok will give that a whirl. Thanks.

Comment: Don't return false if you want the url to update when the tab is clicked.

Comment: Ok Using code froma  couple of you guys, I may have a solution, by reversing the code you created. http://jsfiddle.net/YQdQm/8/
tab1_above is not showing on page load.
Any Suggestions. This may be the way we have to go, without messing with our code too much

Comment: Yeah, I updated your code.

Just changed 

$('#tab1').show();

to $('#tab1_above').show();

Comment: Paul yep brilliant. Is there a way of HIDING all the divs tab1_above , tab2_above etc... until the page has fully loaded ?

Comment: See this, it does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/tXhGe/4/

It also allows you to add more divs. Just add another <div class="tab_content tab1">Test</div> Anywhere in the page and it will show and hide at the same time as the other tab1 areas

Comment: Thats fine, but I would prefer to use http://jsfiddle.net/YQdQm/10/ as it means less fiddling with our code.

Answer (score 3):

You could use jQuery to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/YQdQm/

Not sure if this meets your requirements exactly (also, haven't yet tested on IE).

```
var tabs = $('div[id^=tab]');
tabs.hide();
$('#tab1').show();
$('.tabs a').click(function () {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('href'); 
    tabs.hide();
    $(tab_id).show(); 
});
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for the fiddle, always makes life easier. I was gonna make one but you beat me to it. Cheers

Comment: No problem. Hope it's what you need. Cheers,

Comment: You should change $(this).attr('href') to this.href. No need to wrap a jQuery object around the Element just to access the href property.

Comment: Ok issue I have is, because the tabs generate content BELOW the tabs with the id tab1 , then when I click on the tab, the content ABOVE with id tab1 shows, but the content below the tabs with id tab1 is hidden.. is this becuase there are two id's with same tab id ?

Comment: Thanks, PaulPRO. I'm all for using JavaScript equivalents instead of jQuery where possible. But in this case, `this.href` returns the whole href, which won't work without additional parsing. `this.hash` should work.

Comment: Sorry, 422, I can't see the HTML you're working with, but yes, each div should have a unique id, or you might get unexpected behaviour. I actually changed the id in the jsfiddle to `tab3` for that reason.

Comment: Please see UPDATED post, with Image. This should explain.

Comment: Hi 422, what is the HTML for the divs below the tabs?

Comment: Just TABLES. Which interface with dataTables. an example is: http://jsfiddle.net/YQdQm/1/

Comment: @422 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1527/discussion-between-g-thom-and-422)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use existing [tab control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) from jquery UI

however if not you will need markup like that

```
<div class='tabs'>
<ul>
<li data-id='tab1'>tab 1</li>
....
</ul>
<div id='tab1'></div>
<div id='tab2' class='expanded'></div>
...
</div>
```

and code

```
$('.tabs ul li').bind('click',function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.tabs div').removeClass('expanded');
    $('#'+id).addClass('expanded');    
});
```

Comment: Thanks but for this we do not want to use jQuery Tabs.

Comment: And just importing jQuery + jQuery UI core + jQuery UI Widget + jQuery UI tabs... It's about 250kb of js...

Comment: first, the matter is that problem like this never happen alone, so it is not for just tabs
second, it will be cached and loaded only once, moreover you can use CDN
third, having all this stuff with youtube/vimeo etc sucking gigabytes of traffic talking about 250 kb loaded once is just weird

Comment: My primary concern is the tabs from jquery are huge and I just cannot be arsed , changing all the css , and having gazilllions of unwanted code. Just to accomplish a simple task. I agree with ChristopherCVB . Vittore I will check that code and test thankyou

Comment: @422: i agree that this task is rather simple. my concern is that there is usually a lot of small tasks like this on ajax-enabled website, and you will add one item by one and will end up with a mess instead of tested and modular code, just because these are all small and simple tasks and therefore they are spread into a lot of pages - which is not really convenient. Using lib like jquery ui on the other hand just gives you framework and remove nessessety of a lot of routine tasks, like this one for example

Comment: vittore you are of course correct. We do utilise jQuery UI for a lot of our code. However I am trying to custom code this in the shortest amount of code possible, mainly because I am not JS aware, I build and layer my designs, and then create the functionality client side, and incorporate the integration server side to fire everything up. Its just my NON - Methodical illogical way of working.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit brute force, but I like to do it this way:

JS:

```
    function hidetabs(){
     $("#tab1").hide();
     $("#tab2").hide();
     //And so on
    }

   function shobwtab(id){ 
    $("#"+id).show();
      hidetabs();
   }
```

HTML:

```
   <li><a href="#tab1" onClick="showtab('tab1')"><span class="stateTab">NSW</span></a></li>
```

Of course you could also add click listeners in your docready function to run the functions instead of using onClick.